# PHP Runner - Need Approval Id and Email Alert

Tags: phprunner

In PHPRunner 10.5, there is an encoding webpage, where the user needs to fill in some details from Input boxes then Saves the data. This will generate a unique id.

But I need to make a separate id (approval id) that will be used for email alert.

Sample table structure

| id | business unit | model | output | date_added | approval_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | samsung | q1111 | 17,000 | 2023-10-21 | 8888-20231021 |
| 2 | amazon | w2222 | 8,500 | 2023-10-21 | 8888-20231021 |
| 3 | amazon | e3333 | 10,900 | 2023-10-21 | 8888-20231021 |

where the format of approval will get from the user username upon loging in the webpage
and the date the data was added.

Example user login username : 8888
Date added the datas : 2023-10-21

after these, there will be a separate summary webpage for the summary of approval status for each approval id.